# Rails - Sortable and Highlighted Columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting

I am trying to highlight a column title in Rails, I have followed the following tutorial to create ascending and descending sortable columns (http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns). However I can't make the higlighting working.

Here is the code I ve been using :

**for the view :**

> ```
> %table#movies<br/>
>  %thead<br/>
>   %tr<br/>
>       %th{:id => 'title_header'}= sortable "title", "Movie Title"<br/>
>       %th Rating<br/>
>       %th= sortable "release_date", "Release Date"<br/>
>       %th More Info<br/>
> ```

**the application helper :**

> ```
> module ApplicationHelper
>  def sortable(column, title = nil)
>     title ||= column.titleize
>     css_class = column == sort_column ? "hilite" : nil      
>     direction = column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
>     link_to title, {:sort => column, :direction => direction}, {:class => css_class}
>  end
> end
> ```

**the controller :**

> ```
> def index
>   @movies = Movie.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
> end
> ```
>
> **and**
>
> ```
> def sort_column
>   Movie.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "title"
> end
>
> def sort_direction
>   %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "asc"
>  end
> ```

**and the stylesheet :**

> ```
> table#movies th.hilite {
>   background-color: yellow;
> }
> ```

I can't find whats wrong, but when I click on the header it is only sorting and not highlighting in yellow... suspect that it has something to do with the *css_class*.

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What does the rendered html look like? I'm going to upvote your question, because I have to add this to my project soon, and I don't see any problems with what you've done!

Comment: You can also try to use [ransack](http://railscasts.com/episodes/370-ransack) It's pretty straightforward.

Comment: As i added, the sorting is working pretty well however it is not highlighting in Yellow.
Regarding Ransack, thank for the advice but i'd like to learn to develop it from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's because the class `hilite` isn't on the table header(`<th>`) element but on the anchor (`<a>`) element. Therefor in order to match the element, the CSS would need to be:

```
table#movies th a.hilite {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

So you either need to fix up your CSS or fix up which element you are putting the class on.

Answer (score 0):

Thansks Link, got it, had to test the sorting before runing the sortable helper :

> ```
> %table#movies
>     %thead
>       %tr
>         %th{params[:sort] == "title" ? {:class => "hilite"} : {}, :id => "title_header"}= sortable "title", "Movie Title"
>         %th Rating
>         %th{params[:sort] == "release_date" ? {:class => "hilite"} : {}, :id => 'release_date_header'}= sortable "release_date", "Release Date"
>         %th More Info
> ```

Thanks all for your answers!
Benjamin